# AlertDialog появляется дважды

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
При создании диалога, у меня почему-то появляется тот самый диалог, который я хочу, а за ним появляется диалог в виде label который указан в AndroidManifest... Почему это может происходить?
Вот код самого диалога:

Java:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final String[] fontSize = {"Маленький шрифт", "Средний шрифт", "Большой шрифт"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Заголовок")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(fontSize, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (fontSize[which].equals("Маленький шрифт")) {
                            TEXT = MainActivity.SMALL_TEXT;
                        } else if (fontSize[which].equals("Средний шрифт")) {
                            TEXT = MainActivity.MEDIUM_TEXT;
                        } if (fontSize[which].equals("Большой шрифт")) {
                            TEXT = MainActivity.BIG_TEXT;
                        }
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
    }
```

Манифест:

```
<activity
            android:name=".FontSizeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Dialog">
```

Так же я попытался переопределить тему Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert что бы убрать label:

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

При попытке убрать label в коде с помощью `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`
Приложение вылетает в эксепшн...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а зачем вы для активити используете стиль диалога?

Если вы хотите, чтобы активити и была диалогом, то задавайте ей стиль диалога в манифесте, как вы сделали - она будет отображаться не на весь экран.

Если хотите, чтобы из активити вызывался диалог, то используйте `AlertDialog.Builder` или `DialogFragment`, тогда на фоне активити появится диалог.

Не нужно использовать оба эти способа сразу - получается, что у вас активити в виде диалога вызывает еще один диалог.
Нужно либо для активити установить полноразмерную тему, какой-нибудь модный сейчас `Theme.Appcompat.Light`, либо не вызывать диалогов из активити с темой диалога, тогда всю логику диалога делаете прямо в активити, единственным отличием от полноразмерной у нее будет, собственно, меньший размер.

Comment: Ох, я понял как я затупил) спасибо, Вы открыли мне глаза))